# angularjs: gettext not working in ngSwitch

Tags: angularjs, gettext, ng-switch, angular-gettext

I'm trying to use gettext in combination with ngSwithc, as follows:

```
<ANY ng-switch="expression">
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue1" translate>...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue2" translate>...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-default translate>...</ANY>
</ANY>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/909/) is a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue. The error I get is

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ngSwitchWhen, translate] asking for transclusion on: <div ng-switch-when="opt0" translate="">
```

Any suggestion how I can use gettext in combination with ngSwitch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix is move `translate` attribute to another tag inside the `switch` tags

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this in slightly a different manner making use of a translate service and such.

```
<div>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectLocale" ng-model="selectedLocale"
        ng-options="locale as translate(locale.name) for locale in locales">
    </select>
</div>
```

This enabled me to add a function on the $scope to get the translated string by calling

```
$scope.translate = function(str) {
    return LanguageService.getTranslatedString(str);
};
```

Now every time the select iterates through the array it will call this function to translate the string for you. For more information on the select tag, check out [a AngularJS: API: select directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) in the documentation.

Please visit my blog entry [a Angular-GetText Snippets](http://outofmemoryexception.wordpress.com/2014/04/03/angular-gettext-snippets/) for more in depth information.